# SQL date more than 14 days after original

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I need to pull dates for one column (hire date) but need to get dates more than 14 days after that date.. What's a basic script for that..

Answer (score 1):

Dates in oracle can be used with the plus and minus operators to add and subtract days.  So if you subtract one date from another to get the difference:

```
select * from table
where otherdate - hiredate > 14
```

It is not really clear to me from the question what you are referring to by 'that date', but whether it is another column in the same table, a parameter or something else entirely just replace it in the query as needed.

Comment: To be more accurate, dates are not stored as numbers per se (Oracle has its own particular internal storage format), but the arithmetic operators `+` and `-` and comparison operators (`>`, `<` etc) do work on them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM employees
WHERE 1=1
  AND DateDiff(day,  interestingDate , hirdDate ) >14
```

-- Oops - that was Sql Serrver - sorry about that!  Here is one way to do it in Oracle 9i and up. I like the explicit numtodsinterval function since it is very clear that you are lokoing for Days difference:

```
select *
from employees
WHEERE 1=1
  AND numtodsinterval(interestingDate- hiredDate,'day')>14;
```

Cheers,

Daniel

Comment: DateDiff isn't available in Oracle.  That's a SQL Server-ism.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't compare an interval to a number, so that's not going to work.  You could say `numToDSInterval( date2 - date1, 'day' ) > interval '14' day` to compare two intervals.